# Dynamically change content scraped with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am developing a website which collates information from several weather/snow information sites for mountain walking in Scotland. I currently have a page which uses an iFrame to fetch and show an avalanche report map for a region and a series of links which call a javascript function to change the map shown for different locations.
I am now adding in a scraping method in php to pull the text report from a seperate page on the original site and add it with the map. I've got that function working ok but what I am struggling with is how to change this text content when the user chooses a location by clicking on the link.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Preferably I want to do it without refreshing the page (should I be using something like Ajax for the whole thing?). Here are the 2 scripts I have at the moment:

PHP Scraping script:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('http://www.sais.gov.uk/page_Creag%20Meagaidh.asp');
    $regex = '/Observed Weather Influences........(.+?)\W\Wp\W/';
    $preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
    echo $match[1];
?>
```

Javascript map change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMap(val) {
        frame=document.getElementById('avalanchemap');
        frame.src="http://www.sais.gov.uk/summary_report.asp?area_id=" + val;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Daniel Lisik please don't edit the code itself in questions. You may accidentally cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's not required but will simplify the process for you (doesn't sound like you're that confident) :

Set up a container div in your HTML. And add a script like so:

```
$('.dropdown-or-whatever').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/the_location/_of_your_script.php',
        success: function(result){
            $("#your-container-div").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The change() function on the first line is assuming you're using a dropdown (select) element, which might not be correct.

You'll also (probably) want to pass your PHP script different parameters based on which dropdown choice is selected and scrape a different page depending what that's set to. Parameters can be added at the end of the URL string like so:

```
?place=scotland
```

Any questions, just ask.

**Edit: got bored and basically did it for you. http://pastebin.com/np7GVh3f Take a look at the code and hopefully you'll learn something :)**

Comment: If you dont cast that script from http://www.domain.com/, then it is crossdomain request and it will be not possible.

Comment: It won't be a crossdomain request because it will be on his server.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier - important phone calls always come at bad times :D Thanks very much for this. I'll look over it and see if I can work it out. You're right I am not confident with this - I've never really done more than basic HTML5/CSS/PHP websites before so this is new for me. I'm always ready to learn new stuff though (kinda the whole point of this web project) so thanks very much!